# Problems consuming webservice on production(IIS) server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I need to write web servive, that consume web service.

I have a web service with outher certificate. I make a web application, that use this web service. It starts work in my visual studio. Ok, I moved it over IIS on serwer and:

- on 'localhost' (http:// localhost :51191/test.aspx) it works -> page is shown, and method sucessfull invoke a remote web service
- on normal IIS, .aspx works,  but web service return 403 error (http:// localhost :81/test/test.aspx) -> test.aspx works, but web method invoke return 403 error

I give permissions to that catalog for administrator, and IIS_IUSRS

Comment: can you access the webservice using the direct WS url from your machine?

Comment: Can you give the full Error you got for 403 error

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the server link works from your machine e.g. `http:// <sever name> :81/test/test.aspx`
2. If it doesn't work give permission for `Everyone` to the folder and see if you have access. This will help you to narrow down if its issue with permission or not
3. Launch from Internet Explorer on the server for the link `http:// <sever name> :81/test/test.aspx` (Not with localhost)

And see if this link helps - http://forums.asp.net/t/1860412.aspx?403+Forbidden+error+When+calling+webservice+method+from+ASP+net+Application